# Tied rank adjustment for Spearman Correlation

Tags: matlab, discrete-signals, signal-analysis, correlation

I have two 16 sample vectors, `a` and `b` as listed below:

```
a = 345.86  349.83  257.84  438.43  195.03  0   341.39  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0

b = 313.30  349.83  0   394.07  195.03  257.84  0   0   0   0   0   341.39  0   0   0   0
```

My aim is to calculate the Spearman correlation between the two vectors. I know that it can be done easily in MATLAB by using the function:

```
corr(a,b,'Type','Spearman');
```

However, my aim is to calculate this step by step, i.e.

1. Calculating the ranks of vectors `a` and  `b`
2. Applying the formula $C=1−\frac{6\Sigma(R_x−R_y)^2}{n(n^2−1)}$
3. Adjusting the tied ranks (most important part)

Firstly, using the function `corr(a,b,'Type','Spearman')` I get the correlation coefficient as `0.5845`.

Now as to calculate the same step by step, I am using the `tiedrank` function to calculate the ranks for the vectors `a` and `b`. From [The Mathworks documentation](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/stats/tiedrank.html?requestedDomain=uk.mathworks.com):

> `[R,TIEADJ] = tiedrank(X)` computes the ranks of the values in the vector X. If any X values are tied, tiedrank computes their average rank. The return value TIEADJ is an adjustment for ties required by the nonparametric tests signrank and ranksum, and for the computation of Spearman's rank correlation.

Using this for the above example, I get the following:

```
Rank_a = 14 15  12  16  11  5.5 13  5.5 5.5 5.5 5.5 5.5 5.5 5.5 5.5 5.5

Rank_b = 13 15  5.5 16  11  12  5.5 5.5 5.5 5.5 5.5 14  5.5 5.5 5.5 5.5
```

And the Tied Adjustments that I get:

```
TIEDADJ_a = 495

TIEDADJ_b = 495
```

So, later I calculate the differences of squares of the ranks between `a` and `b` i.e. Sum of `(Rank_a(i) - Rank_b(i))^2` which is equal to `214`.

I do not know how to take into account the `TIEDADJ_a` and `TIEDADJ_b` values in addition to the above summation of difference of ranks calculated, so that I can achieve the correlation coefficient calculated by the MATLAB function directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After finding the two rank vectors `Rank_a` and `Rank_b`, just calculate the correlation coefficient of ranks:

`c = cov(Rank_a,Rank_b)/(std(Rank_a)*std(Rank_a))`

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman's_rank_correlation_coefficient), you can only use 
$$C=1−\frac{6\Sigma(R_x−R_y)^2}{n(n^2−1)}$$ if the ranks are **distinct integer values** (in this case are not).

> If ties are present in the data set, this equation yields incorrect results.

Comment: Yes, that is true. I actually encountered a link on MATLAB Central which does the same. However, I want to understand the significance of the TIEDADJ parameter calculated in the tiedrank function. I want to know how that parameter is used for calculation (whether if it is used) of the correlation.

Comment: Here is the MATLAB Central Link:

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/27406